# For which distributions of X, the expected value E[X] equal to arithmetic mean?

Tags: expected-value

For which distributions of X, the expected value of X (i.e., E[X]) is equal to the arithmetic mean of X?

Comment: This will only hold for degenerate distributions, i.e., ones with only one possible value for $X$.  What do you really mean to ask?

Comment: One definition of the "arithmetic mean" of a random variable $X$ is its expectation $E[X].$ Please explain, then, what distinction you are making between the two.

Answer (score 2):

**Note on interpretation:** It is not entirely clear what you mean by the "arithmetic mean" of the random variable $X$.  If you are referring to the sample mean of a bunch of samples of $X$ then your question is trivial, and is answered correctly by [jbowman](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/7555/jbowman) in the comments.  In order to make sense of your question, I'm going to assume that by "arithmetic mean" in this context, you are referring to the average of all values in the support of the distribution.  (Note that this is only well-defined for distributions with finite support.)  That interpretation would make "arithmetic mean" a property of the distribution of a single random variable $X$, which is how you have framed your question.  Note that this is an unusual question, so you should consider whether it is really what you are seeking to ask.

---

**Definition:** Consider a random variable $X$ with a distribution that has finite support $\mathscr{X}$.  For purposes of this answer we will define the **arithmetic mean** of this distribution as the value:

$$\mathbb{A}(X) \equiv \frac{1}{|\mathscr{X}|} \sum_{x \in \mathscr{X}} x.$$

---

**Theorem:** Consider a random variable $X$ with a distribution that has finite support $\mathscr{X}$ and has probability mass function $p_X$ over that support.  Let $\mathbf{x}$ denote the vector of values in the support (in any order) and let $\mathbf{p}$ denote the corresponding probability mass values (in the same order).  If $|\mathscr{X}| = 1$ then $\mathbb{A}(X) = \mathbb{E}(X)$, and if $|\mathscr{X}| > 1$ then we have:

$$\mathbb{A}(X) = \mathbb{E}(X) \quad \quad \quad \iff \quad \quad \quad r(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{p}) = 0,$$

where $r$ denotes the formula for the [sample correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence#Sample_correlation_coefficient) of two vectors.

**Proof:** If $|\mathscr{X}| = 1$ then $\mathbb{A}(X) = \mathbb{E}(X)$ follows trivially.  We therefore proceed for the non-trivial case where $|\mathscr{X}| > 1$ (for which the sample correlation is well-defined).  Let $C(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{p})$ denote the sample covariance between $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{p}$.  We have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
(|\mathscr{X}|-1) C(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{p})
&= \sum_{x \in \mathscr{X}} (x - \mathbb{A}(X)) \Big( p_X(x) - \frac{1}{|\mathscr{X}|} \Big) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{x \in \mathscr{X}} x \Big( p_X(x) - \frac{1}{|\mathscr{X}|} \Big) - \mathbb{A}(X) \sum_{x \in \mathscr{X}} \Big( p_X(x) - \frac{1}{|\mathscr{X}|} \Big) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{x \in \mathscr{X}} x \Big( p_X(x) - \frac{1}{|\mathscr{X}|} \Big) - \mathbb{A}(X) (1-1) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{x \in \mathscr{X}} x \Big( p_X(x) - \frac{1}{|\mathscr{X}|} \Big) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{x \in \mathscr{X}} x \cdot p_X(x) - \frac{1}{|\mathscr{X}|} \sum_{x \in \mathscr{X}} x \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}(X) - \mathbb{A}(X). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

This establishes that $C(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{p}) = 0$ if and only if $\mathbb{E}(X) = \mathbb{A}(X)$.  Since  $C(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{p}) = 0$ if and only if $r(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{p}) = 0$ the result follows by transitivity.  $\blacksquare$

---

From the above theorem, we can see that the requirement for equivalence is satisfied if and only if the vector of values in the support $\mathscr{X}$ is uncorrelated with the corresponding vector of probabilities.  This gives us a simple test that can be applied to any distribution with finite support to see if its expected value is equal to its "arithmetic mean" (as defined here).  There are and infinite number of discrete distributions in which this equation will hold.

**Example:** Consider the discrete distribution with:

$$p_X(0) = 0.4 \quad \quad \quad p_X(1) = 0.2 \quad \quad \quad p_X(2) = 0.4.$$

This distribution satisfies the requirement that the probability vector is uncorrelated with the vector of values in its support (defined so that the elements correspond).  For this distribution we have "arithmetic mean":

$$\frac{1}{|\mathscr{X}|} \sum_{x \in \mathscr{X}} x = \frac{1}{3} (0+1+2) = \frac{3}{3} = 1,$$

and expected value:

$$\sum_{x \in \mathscr{X}} x \cdot p_X(x) = (0 \cdot 0.4 + 1 \cdot 0.2 + 2 \cdot 0.4) = 0.2+0.8 = 1.$$

Comment: Re the introduction: the Poisson is a discrete distribution with support $0, 1, 2, \ldots.$  What would the average of all those values be?  One has to wonder what the OP is trying to ask... .

Comment: Thanks - Edited - I meant finite, not just discrete.  I've also elaborated on interpretation at the start.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and for correctly interpreting my question.

Comment: @user130451: Glad to see I guessed the intended interpretation correctly!  (I only just managed to sneak the answer in these before it was put on hold!)